New volume error message: The media is write protected
My customer has several volumes on his Windows computer. In order to test something, I'm trying to get the same situation, so I have shrunken my main disk (C:-drive) and created a new volume (on the D:-drive). At first, everything seems fine:
Computer Management screenshot:

I have formatted that disk, using Format D:, as you can see in this excerpt of the commandline prompt (run as administrator):
C:\WINDOWS\system32>format d:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Enter current volume label for drive D: Application_Logs

WARNING, ALL DATA ON NON-REMOVABLE DISK
DRIVE D: WILL BE LOST!
Proceed with Format (Y/N)? Y
Formatting 9,8 GB
Volume label (32 characters, ENTER for none)? Application_Logs
Creating file system structures.
Format complete.
       9,8 GB total disk space.
       9,7 GB are available.

However, when I try to get something done on that new drive, I get as a response that the media is write protected:
D:\>mkdir Logs
The media is write protected.

I tried to modify the user rights on that drive but this fails:


Does this computer perhaps have a “BitLocker required” policy active?

That might be possible: I've seen the Bitlocker information on the C:-drive's properties, but I have no idea what this means nor how to apply this on my D:-drive.

That would mean you cannot write to volumes until they are BitLocker-encrypted.

@DanielB: thanks. I went to "Control Panel", "System and Security", "Bitlocker Drive Encryption" and there I enabled Bitlocker on my newly created volume.

(Not entirely sure if this worked for you.)

Using Group Policy or MDM Policy, administrators can require that drives be encrypted using BitLocker. They can select to only require this for internal drives or to also require it for removable drives.
This is mainly to prevent information theft. As such, reading from an unencrypted drive is still possible. Windows will effectively pretend the drive is write-protected, triggering all the symptoms you see.
To encrypt the newly created partition, simply type “BitLocker” in the Start menu search, then go to “Manage BitLocker”. This will take you to the legacy control panel (even on Windows 11). From there, you will be able to enable BitLocker for the partition (or “drive”, in Windows speak). You will then be able to write to the partition.
Encrypting a freshly created partition should be very quick, because only used space is encrypted.
